# react-native's Linking api not opening the url in the browser after openURL()

Tags: react-native, redirect

I have made a button as:

```
<-Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL(props.albumName.url)} /->
```

upon pressing the button, the app isnt getting redirected to a new browser window. I checked it in the AVD as well as on my Android phone. The parameter `props.albumName.url == https://www.amazon.com/Evolve-Imagine-Dragons/dp/B07143J5MM/`. Other properties such as `props.albumName.title`, `props.albumName.artist` etc are being displayed correctly so nothing wrong with the syntax, I also tried logging `props.albumName.url` out to confirm that it contains the given url in the correct format

Comment: ignore the hyphen just after the opening tag and right before the closing tag.

Comment: Try this `<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://google.com'); } />`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing title property in button tag, it's a required props.

I have tried the same code, it works great.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Linking,
  Button
} from 'react-native';


export default class Button1 extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <View>
           <Button
            title="click" 
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(this.props.albumName)}/>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

And am using that component here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 StyleSheet,
 Text,
 View
} from 'react-native';

import Button1 from './Button';



export default class App extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
      Welcome to React Native!
    </Text>`enter code here`
    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
      To get started, edit App.js
    </Text>
    <Button1 albumName = 'https://www.amazon.com/Evolve-Imagine- 
  Dragons/dp/B07143J5MM/' />
  </View>
 );
 }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
 welcome: {
fontSize: 20,
textAlign: 'center',
margin: 10,
},
instructions: {
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#333333',
marginBottom: 5,
},
});
```

Comment: How you added browsable in your manifest's intent filter for this?